# Using & Replacing Multiple Viewpagers for showing fragments with tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-viewpager

This question is more about code optimization.
Im displaying 3 viewpagers in my app. each one of them has 2 tabs. every time i want to display a fragment that it is on other viewpager than the active viewpager im replacing the viewpager.
Is this a good idea? sometimes i get a 400ms delay on replacing. Should i do something else?
Here is the code that replaces viewpagers:

```
private void SetCurrentViewpager(PagerAdapterTypesEnum personTypesEnum = PagerAdapterTypesEnum.OddEven)
        {
            switch (personTypesEnum)
            {
                case PagerAdapterTypesEnum.OddEven:
                    if (CurrentViewPagerAdapter is PagerAdapterOddEven)
                        return;
                    CurrentTabLayout.RemoveAllTabs();
                    CurrentTabLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    CurrentTabLayout.AddTab(CurrentTabLayout.NewTab().SetText(GetString(Resource.String.OddEven_ResultsTabTitle)));
                    CurrentTabLayout.AddTab(CurrentTabLayout.NewTab().SetText(GetString(Resource.String.OddEven_DelaysTabTitle)));
                    CurrentTabLayout.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;

                    CurrentViewPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapterOddEven
                        (SupportFragmentManager, CurrentTabLayout.TabCount);
                    CurrentViewPager.Adapter = CurrentViewPagerAdapter;

                    CurrentViewPager.AddOnPageChangeListener(null);
                    break;
                case PagerAdapterTypesEnum.Search:
                    if (CurrentViewPagerAdapter is PagerAdapterSearch)
                        return;
                    CurrentTabLayout.RemoveAllTabs();
                    CurrentTabLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    CurrentTabLayout.AddTab(CurrentTabLayout.NewTab().SetText(GetString(Resource.String.Search)));
                    CurrentTabLayout.AddTab(CurrentTabLayout.NewTab().SetText(GetString(Resource.String.NumbersSearch_BonusAndFrequency)));
                    CurrentTabLayout.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;

                    CurrentViewPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapterSearch
                        (SupportFragmentManager, CurrentTabLayout.TabCount);
                    CurrentViewPager.Adapter = CurrentViewPagerAdapter;

                    CurrentViewPager.AddOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(CurrentTabLayout));
                    CurrentTabLayout.TabSelected += (object sender, TabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        CurrentViewPager.SetCurrentItem(e.Tab.Position, true);
                    };
                    break;
                case PagerAdapterTypesEnum.Columns:
                    if (CurrentViewPagerAdapter is PagerAdapterColumns)
                        return;
                    CurrentTabLayout.RemoveAllTabs();
                    CurrentTabLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    CurrentTabLayout.AddTab(CurrentTabLayout.NewTab().SetText(GetString(Resource.String.Columns_ColumnsStatistics)));
                    CurrentTabLayout.AddTab(CurrentTabLayout.NewTab().SetText(GetString(Resource.String.Columns_ColumnsResultsPerNumbers)));
                    CurrentTabLayout.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;

                    CurrentViewPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapterColumns
                        (SupportFragmentManager, CurrentTabLayout.TabCount);
                    CurrentViewPager.Adapter = CurrentViewPagerAdapter;

                    CurrentViewPager.AddOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(CurrentTabLayout));
                    CurrentTabLayout.TabSelected += (object sender, TabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        CurrentViewPager.SetCurrentItem(e.Tab.Position, true);
                    };
                    break;
                case PagerAdapterTypesEnum.Settings:
                    if (CurrentViewPagerAdapter is PagerAdapterSettings)
                        return;
                    CurrentTabLayout.RemoveAllTabs();
                    CurrentTabLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    CurrentTabLayout.AddTab(CurrentTabLayout.NewTab().SetText(GetString(Resource.String.Columns_ColumnsStatistics)));
                    CurrentTabLayout.AddTab(CurrentTabLayout.NewTab().SetText(GetString(Resource.String.Columns_ColumnsResultsPerNumbers)));
                    CurrentTabLayout.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;

                    CurrentViewPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapterSettings
                        (SupportFragmentManager, CurrentTabLayout.TabCount);
                    CurrentViewPager.Adapter = CurrentViewPagerAdapter;

                    CurrentViewPager.AddOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(CurrentTabLayout));
                    CurrentTabLayout.TabSelected += (object sender, TabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        CurrentViewPager.SetCurrentItem(e.Tab.Position, true);
                    };

                    break;
            }
        }

public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;
            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);

            if (id == Resource.Id.Nav_DrawSearch)
            {
                SetCurrentViewpager(PagerAdapterTypesEnum.Search);
                CurrentTabLayout.GetTabAt(0).Select();
            }
            else if (id == Resource.Id.Nav_DrawsPerFrequency)
            {
                SetCurrentViewpager(PagerAdapterTypesEnum.Search);
                CurrentTabLayout.GetTabAt(1).Select();
            }
            else if (id == Resource.Id.Nav_OddEvenResults)
            {
                SetCurrentViewpager(PagerAdapterTypesEnum.OddEven);
                CurrentTabLayout.GetTabAt(0).Select();
            }
            else if (id == Resource.Id.Nav_OddEvenDelays)
            {
                SetCurrentViewpager(PagerAdapterTypesEnum.OddEven);
                CurrentTabLayout.GetTabAt(1).Select();
            }
            else if (id == Resource.Id.Nav_ColumnsStatistics)
            {
                SetCurrentViewpager(PagerAdapterTypesEnum.Columns);
                CurrentTabLayout.GetTabAt(0).Select();
            }
            else if (id == Resource.Id.Nav_ColumnsResultsPerNumbers)
            {
                SetCurrentViewpager(PagerAdapterTypesEnum.Columns);
                CurrentTabLayout.GetTabAt(1).Select();
            }
            else if (id == Resource.Id.Nav_Settings)
            {
                SetCurrentViewpager(PagerAdapterTypesEnum.Settings);
                CurrentTabLayout.GetTabAt(0).Select();
            }


            drawer.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: `sometimes i get a 400ms delay on replacing.` Do you have lots of picture or other internet connection in the these pages? And please use android device to make a test, android emualtor load the fragment have 400m delay is acceptabel. If you have internet connection or load data, please use `await/async`.

Comment: Thank you @Leon for the comment. I just load some variables from shared preferences. 400ms is not really an issue if my approach is a good one. I was more concerned if my approach was a hack and there was a different much better way.

Comment: ` load some variables from shared preferences.` If you want to store varieables to a secure stroage, you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android, based on my experience, you design is ok.